# Installing Wi-fi Drivers on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: drivers, server, wireless, 20.04, usb

I recently purchased a USB Wi-fi Adapter from Amazon for my Ubuntu server. The reviews say that it is compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 but the drivers for Ubuntu don't come on the included driver CD. I was wondering where I could find the correct drivers for the adapter. The adapter is linked below. If anyone can help, that'd be very appreciated.

Wi-fi Adapter: [https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-Wireless-WiFi-Adapter-Black/dp/B08M9FX4G3/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2J7B1T0MVKY2R&dchild=1&keywords=ugreen+wifi+adapter&qid=1630604360&sprefix=ugreen+wifi%2Caps%2C200&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08M9FX4G3)

Journalctl --follow interesting lines: https://pastebin.com/xcmpn25A

lsusb output: https://pastebin.com/JxvPdWCs

lsusb -v output for wifi adapter: https://gyazo.com/e0d0c5d7fb740accf32d23951c7805c5, https://gyazo.com/94f36095fef12c29b815354ab537ee03

Comment: Does the adapter work? What does `lsusb` output? In most cases you don't need drivers.

Comment: Unplug the adapter. In a terminal window, `sudo journalctl  --follow`. Enter your login password when prompted. Then plug the adapter in. After things settle, stop the `journalctl --follow` by typing `^C`. Carefully read each line, and [Edit] your question  to add (copy, paste,format) the interesting ones

Comment: @waltinator , I've edited the original post with the Journalctl --follow interesting lines.

Comment: @Pilot6 , I've edited the original post with the lsusb output.

Comment: @waltinator dmesg may work better here with the `--facility [list] --kernel` options. I'm not sure which facilities would return usb/wifi related logs, but I guarantee they exist. : )

Comment: what options are given on the dick that came with it? would you mind listing the file names? Also, can you rerun `lsusb` but as `lsusb -v ` and post the section following `Bus 001 Device 004` in the output. IJt will tell if ther is a stock driver loaded for it.

Comment: @NateT I've posted the lsusb -v output for the wifi adapter.